# Why do CKEDITOR uploaded images give 404 errors in rails production site?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, capistrano

I am using ckeditor and when uploading images on the production site its fine but when I make a change to the site and deploy with Capistrano it shows 404 errors for the images.

In my:

## production.rb I have:

```
  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
  config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
  config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)
```

Then in my

## application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

In my

## lib/tasks/ckeditor.rake I have this:

```
require 'fileutils'

desc "Create nondigest versions of all ckeditor digest assets"
task "assets:precompile" do
  fingerprint = /\-[0-9a-f]{32}\./
  for file in Dir["public/assets/ckeditor/**/*"]
    next unless file =~ fingerprint
    nondigest = file.sub fingerprint, '.'
    FileUtils.cp file, nondigest, verbose: true
  end
end
```

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Comment: What is the URL of such an image? And what do you expect the URL to be?

Answer (score 0):

It is because where CKEditor gem is storing the assets is not inside the symlinked folder that all your releases share. In my setup public/system is a symlink to a shared folder that all production releases share. When the admin uploads the image via CKeditor it needs to get placed inside that folder so it is shared. I did this by making my own `Ckeditor::AttachmentFile < Ckeditor::Asset` model in `/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb`

In that file I have:

```
has_attached_file :data,
                :url => "/system/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/system/ckeditor_assets/attachments/:id/:filename"

def store_dir
  "public/system/ckeditor_assets/attachments/#{model.id}"
 end
```

Which moves the ckeditor files into my symlinked system folder so they can be shared between releases. You will also have to do something similar for `Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset`

This may not be the preferred method but hopefully leads you in the right direction.

Comment: do I need to add this into my Capistrano setup? I know I have the system folder already. In deployment does this folder get ignored with a precompile when its on production?